# what are the differences between /mnt and /media?

Tags: filesystems

In FHS, /mnt is provided so that the system administrator may temporarily mount a filesystem as needed.

And, /media contains subdirectories that are used as mount points for removable media such as floppy disks, CD-ROMs and, zip disks.

### So, what are the differences between these two directories?

If I mount CD temporarily, then which directory should be used?
If /mnt is not for permanently mounted devices, then removable devices(which should be mounted in /media) are "Permanently Mounted" devices?

Comment: You can use whatever you want - there are no real differences. Only historically different usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FHS [explains `/media` thus](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s11.html):

> Historically there have been a number of other different places used to mount removable media such as `/cdrom`, `/mnt` or `/mnt/cdrom`. Placing the mount points for all removable media directly in the root directory would potentially result in a large number of extra directories in `/`. Although the use of subdirectories in `/mnt` as a mount point has recently been common, it conflicts with a much older tradition of using `/mnt` directly as a temporary mount point.

The last sentence explains part of the problem: `/mnt` is traditionally not a directory containing mount points, it’s the mount point itself (*e.g.* `mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt`). Of course nowadays both `/mnt` and `/media` are typically directories containing mount points, which avoids the issue, but it doesn’t have to be the case.

Another issue is that [`/mnt` is explicitly the system administrator’s domain](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s12.html), which means that programs which want to mount file systems themselves can’t expect to be able to use it. That’s how I tend to think of `/media` versus `/mnt`: `/media` is where removable devices are mounted by desktop environments etc., whereas `/mnt` is where I (as the system administrator) mount file systems when I need to. I never touch `/media` directly.